# WP_User_Query with more than two custom meta values

Tags: query, users, wp-user-query

I am trying to create a custom user query based on users' metadata. I have the following query created.

```
$users = new WP_User_Query( 
  array(  
    'search' => '*' . $search_name . '*',
    'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'key' => 'Status',
        'value' => $search_status,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
      ),
      array(
        'key' => 'Operation',
        'value' => $search_operation,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
      ),
      array(
        'key' => 'visible_to_directory',
        'value' => '1',
        'compare' => '='
      )
    )
  )
);
```

When I have two custom meta values, it works great. Once I add more than that, it doesn't seem to work. Is this not supported with the WP_User_Query class?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the answer was not found in my query, as it is correct. I was not passing variables to the query properly.

From my research, there is no constraint on the number of custom meta queries you can place in one query.